# How to read from a list of maps containing lists of maps?

Tags: flutter, list, dart

I am trying to read data from a list fetched from an API. I want to fetch the `title` key in the nested list with key `questions`.

Here is the response expected from the API call.

```
[
  {
    "id": "string",
    "quizId": "string",
    "userId": "string",
    "lessonId": "string",
    "courseId": "string",
    "correct_Answered": 0,
    "wrong_Answered": 0,
    "datePlayed": "2022-11-02T22:17:09.353Z",
    "questions": [
      {
        "questionId": "string",
        "title": "string",
        "pass": true,
        "completed": "2022-11-02T22:17:09.353Z",
        "rightAnswers": [
          "string"
        ],
        "options": [
          "string"
        ],
        "selectedOptions": [
          "string"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "quizScore": 0,
    "questionCount": 0
  }
]
```

The code I wrote to read the outer list works, but the one for the nested list is not working.
Here is the code

```
final quizHistoryData = json.decode(postQuizResponse.body);
      final List<QuizHistory> quizHistoryHolder = [];
      final List<QuizHistory> quizTitleHolder = [];
      for (var item in quizHistoryData) {
        quizHistoryHolder.add(QuizHistory(
            id: item['id'],
            quizId: item['quizId'],
            userId: item['userId'],
            courseId: item['courseId'],
            lessonId: item['lessonId'],
            correctlyAnswered: item['correct_Answered'],
            wronglyAnswered: item['wrong_Answered'],
            datePlayed: item['datePlayed'],
            questions: item['questions'],
            quizScore: item['quizScore'],
            questionCount: item['questionCount']));
            for (var item in item['questions']) {
              quizTitleHolder.add(QuizHistory(questionTitle: item['title']));
              print('Quiz history title is ${questionTitle}');
            }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend serializing JSON inside model classes and having seperate models for Question and Quiz data.

```
class QuizHistory {
  QuizHistory(
    this.id,
    this.quizId,
    this.userId,
    this.lessonId,
    this.courseId,
    this.correctAnswered,
    this.wrongAnswered,
    this.datePlayed,
    this.questions,
  );

  QuizHistory.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : id = json['id'] as String,
        quizId = json['quizId'] as String,
        userId = json['userId'] as String,
        lessonId = json['lessonId'] as String,
        courseId = json['courseId'] as String,
        correctAnswered = json['correctAnswered'] as int,
        wrongAnswered = json['wrongAnswered'] as int,
        datePlayed = json['datePlayed'] as String,
        questions = (json['questions'] as List<dynamic>)
            .map((e) => Question.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
            .toList();

  final String id;
  final String quizId;
  final String userId;
  final String lessonId;
  final String courseId;
  final int correctAnswered;
  final int wrongAnswered;
  final String datePlayed;
  final List<Question> questions;
}

class Question {
  Question(
    this.questionId,
    this.title,
    this.pass,
    this.completed,
    this.rightAnswers,
    this.options,
    this.selectedOptions,
  );

  Question.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : questionId = json['questionId'] as String,
        title = json['title'] as String,
        pass = json['pass'] as bool,
        completed = json['completed'] as String,
        rightAnswers = json['rightAnswers'] as List<String>,
        options = json['options'] as List<String>,
        selectedOptions = json['selectedOptions'] as List<String>;

  final String questionId;
  final String title;
  final bool pass;
  final String completed;
  final List<String> rightAnswers;
  final List<String> options;
  final List<String> selectedOptions;
}
```

and finally

```
 quizHistoryHolder = jsonData
        .map((e) => QuizHistory.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
        .toList();
```

You might want to use JSON serialization library when you have a lot of models. [Serializing JSON using code generation libraries](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json#serializing-json-using-code-generation-libraries)